# Advantages/Disadvantages of using __int16 (or int16_t) over int

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10

As far as I understand, the number of bytes used for `int` is system dependent. Usually, 2 or 4 bytes are used for `int`.

As per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=vs-2019), `__int8`, `__int16`, `__int32` and `__int64` are Microsoft Specific keywords. Furthermore, `__int16` uses 16-bits (i.e. 2 bytes).

**Question:** What are advantage/disadvantage of using `__int16` (or `int16_t`)? For example, if I am sure that the value of my integer variable will never need more than 16 bits then, will it be beneficial to declare the variable as `__int16 var` (or `int16_t var`)?

**UPDATE:** I see that several comments/answers suggest using `int16_t` instead of `__int16`, which is a good suggestion but not really an advantage/disadvantage of using `__int16`. ***Basically, my question is, what is the advantage/disadvantage of saving 2 bytes by using 16-bit version of an integer instead of*** `int` ?

Comment: Disadvantage: It's Microsoft specific. Use [C++11's fixed ranged integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) instead.

Comment: Always prefer cross-platform solutions to single platform solutions, if it doesn't cost anything.

Comment: @nada: That's obvious disadvantage. Sorry, I forgot to mention that if I am sure that the program will run on a windows machine. Updated my question.

Comment: It might be beneficial to use smaller types, it might also cause the exact opposite. Benchmark where necessary.

Comment: @skm Portability *remains* an issue even if target is guaranteed to be windows. What, if someone want's to compile with MinGW?

Comment: The greatest advantage of fixed range integers is that you have a guarantee for a specific number of bits. C++11 comes additionally with `[u]int_least<N>_t` and `[u]int_fast<N>_t`, first one assures a minimum of N bits, but is possibly larger (e. g. int8_t not existing -> falling back to int16_t), second one assures the same minimum, but chooses fastest type available for (e. g. int32_t even though int8_t exists).

Comment: It helps to remember that today, no CPU running Windows has actual 16 bits registers. They need to be emulated using 64 bit registers.

Comment: @MSalters Hm, I wouldn't [count on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_IoT)...

Comment: It depends heavily on the target architecture.  For x86 and x64 the disadvantage is that the MOV instruction requires one extra byte for the operand size override (0x66 prefix), so doesn't use the L1 I-cache as efficiently.  The advantage is that it only moves 2 bytes, so uses the L1 D-cache more efficiently.  Which only tends to produce a measurable difference when you have an array of them.  Quite hard to profile, you have to experiment with real code to get a reliable indication.

Comment: Hm, maybe reword the question a bit; by referring to int16_t or MS variant of, focus gets far to quick on (dis-)advantages of fixed range integers, however, if I read the update right, you don't care about at all *how* you get those two instead of four bytes, even just using `short` (on *your* system) would have been fine, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Aconcagua: I have reformatted the question a bit. Hope its more clear now. Yes, I am mainly interested to know the advantages/disadvantages of savings bytes by using different n-bits versions of an integer.

Comment: Don't use `__int16`, that's a MSVC++ implementation detail.  From `<cstdint>`, use `std::int16_t` (or if appropriate for your purposes, `std::int_fast16_t` or `std::int_least16_t`).  Microsoft will do the `namespace std { using int16_t = __int16; }` with the implementation detail for you.

Answer (score 2):

Saving 2 bytes is almost never worth it. However, saving thousands of bytes is. If you have an large array containing integers, using a small integer type can save quite a lot of memory. This leads to faster code, because the less memory one uses the less cache misses one receives (cache misses are a major loss of performance).

TL;DR: this is beneficial to do in large arrays, but pointless for 1-off variables.

The second use of these is if for dealing with binary files and messages. If you are reading a binary file that uses 16-bit integers, well, it's pretty convenient if you can represent that type exactly in your code.

BTW, don't use microsoft's versions. Use the standard versions (`std::int16_t`)

Comment: There is the limitation that support of `std::int16_t` by an implementation is optional.

Comment: @Peter Could that rather be an advantage? Implementations usually won't provide the type if they cannot support it, so if we *need* it, we are in trouble anyway. Compilation failing then immediately pushes us onto that, instead of falling back to some type of undesired size...

Comment: @Aconcagua - not arguing with that.  Simply pointing out it is a limitation to be aware of.

Comment: Hm, using binary 16-bit values to read from binary 16-bit sources is just as convenient as it is dangerous. Perhaps fine, if you can rely on equal byte order for both file and CPU, otherwise, there's an issue yet to be considered...

Comment: Well, modulo `ntohs`, yes. Using a larger integer isn't going to solve your byte order problems either.

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason just need a shorter integer type it's already have that in the language - called `short` - unless you know you need exactly 16 bits there's really no good reason not to just stick with the *agnostic* `short` and `int` types. The broad idea is that these types should align well the target architecture (for example see [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) ).

That being said, theres no need to use the platform specific type (`__int16`), you can just use the standard one:

```
int16_t
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer for more information and standard types

Even if you still insist on `__int16` you probably want a typedef something ala.:

```
using my_short = __int16;
```

**Update**

Your main question is:

> What is the advantage/disadvantage of
>   saving 2 bytes by using 16-bit version of an integer instead of int ?

**If you have a lot of data (In the ballpark of at least some 100.000-1.000.000 elements as a rule of thumb) - then there could be an overall performance saving in terms of using less cpu-cache. Overall there's no disadvantage of using a smaller type - except for the obvious one - and possible conversions as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58374399/2261538)**

Comment: Uh, dangerous... There are systems even today (usually embedded ones) where short and int have same size! If you have minimum range requirements *and* want to be portable, you usually are better off with the explicit ranges (possibly preferring the fast over the fix variant, if you care for performance).

Comment: @Aconcagua short and int do have minimums - you need to be fully aware of that !

Comment: I am – and if you peek into standard, those for short and int are the same (just that int is not allowed to be smaller than short)...

Comment: @Aconcagua are you arguing that we should never use short and it has no place in the language ?

Comment: Not that either. But you need to use them carefully, especially if you want to be portable. With the minimum requirements defined, both can be covered with 16 bits (actually, I even worked already with a system having CHAR_BIT == 16 and sizeof(int) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(char)!). It's not an issue if you write code for some very specific system where you know `int` to have 32 bits. But you don't have that guarantee for portable code.

Comment: Another example: You know you need 32 bits, but you have a quite large array (as presented in the other answer), so you don't want to use more either. OK, int might not be sufficient, so fine, then we choose `long`. And then we compile on 64-bit linux just to discover that we use twice the memory as intended. What happended? `long` is 64 bits there...

Comment: The whole point is: **If** you have specific (minimum?) size requirements for the data types, the fixed range integers coming from `<cstdint>` or, if additionally performance matters, their `fast` variants of, allow you to write efficient *and* portable code in a much safer way.

Comment: Hm, with question update, this whole discussion gets less and less relevant (actually, the answer as well): '*Basically, my question is [...]*' – so as it seems it doesn't really matter if we get two instead of 4 bytes by int16_t, MS variant of or short...

Comment: @Aconcagua I guess you are right - I tried to update my answer as a result

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

On x86, primitive types are generally aligned on their size. So 2-byte types would be aligned on a 2-byte boundary. This is useful when you have more than one of these short variables, because you will be saving 50% of space. That directly translates to better memory and cache utilization and thus theoretically, better performance.

On the other hand, doing arithmetic on shorter-than-`int` types usually involves widening conversion to `int`. So if you do a lot of arithmetic on these types, using `int` types might result in better performance ([contrived example](https://godbolt.org/z/Uz50t1)).

So if you care about performance of a critical section of code, ***profile*** it to find out for sure if using a certain data type is faster or slower.

A possible rule of thumb would be - if you're memory-bound (i.e. you have lots of variables and especially arrays), use as short a data types as possible. If not - don't worry about it and use `int` types.

Comment: care to show example (eg. on godbolt) where conversion comes into play ? - i didn't think this could be an issue - and how big is it compared to cache savings ?

Comment: *'So if you care about performance of a critical section of code, profile it [...]'* – pretty likely doing so will reveal the bottleneck actually being elsewhere... ;)

Comment: @darune - any example I post will probably be seen as contrived. Nevertheless, here's [a example](https://godbolt.org/z/Uz50t1). Cache in hot code often isn't an issue, in that case the second version will definitely be slower.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using these types is to make sure about the size of your variable in different architectures and compilers. we call it "code reusability" and "portability"

in higher-level modern languages, all this will handle with compiler/interpreter/virtual machine/etc. that you don't need to worry about, but it has some performance and memory usage costs.

When you have some kind of limitation you may need to optimize everything. The best example is embedded systems that have a very limited size of memory and work at low frequency. In the other hand, there are lots of compilers out there with different implementations. Some of them interpret "int" as a "16bit" value and some as a "32bit".

for example, you receive and specific stream of values over a communication system, you want to save them in a buffer or array and you want to make sure the input data is always interpreted as a 16bit noting else.